# many to many save data

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I have two entity that have manytomany relation

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Esame
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="esame", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_tipologia_esame", columns={"id_tipologia_esame"}), @ORM\Index(name="id_analisi", columns={"id_analisi"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\EsameRepository")
 */
class Esame
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Nome_esame
     *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Nome_esame")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_tipologia_esame", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idTipologiaEsame;

    /**
      * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Analisi
     *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Analisi")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_analisi", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idAnalisi;

  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TipologiaCampione", inversedBy="esami")
     */

    private $campioni;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }







    /**
     * Set idAnalisi
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Analisi $idAnalisi
     *
     * @return Esame
     */
    public function setIdAnalisi($idAnalisi)
    {
        $this->idAnalisi = $idAnalisi;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idAnalisi
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdAnalisi()
    {
        return $this->idAnalisi;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->campioni = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add campioni
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\TipologiaCampione $campioni
     *
     * @return Esame
     */
    public function addCampioni(\AppBundle\Entity\TipologiaCampione $campioni)
    {
        $this->campioni[] = $campioni;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove campioni
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\TipologiaCampione $campioni
     */
    public function removeCampioni(\AppBundle\Entity\TipologiaCampione $campioni)
    {
        $this->campioni->removeElement($campioni);
    }

    /**
     * Get campioni
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCampioni()
    {
        return $this->campioni;
    }

    /**
     * Set idTipologiaEsame
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Nome_esame $idTipologiaEsame
     *
     * @return Esame
     */
    public function setIdTipologiaEsame(\AppBundle\Entity\Nome_esame $idTipologiaEsame = null)
    {
        $this->idTipologiaEsame = $idTipologiaEsame;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idTipologiaEsame
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Nome_esame
     */
    public function getIdTipologiaEsame()
    {
        return $this->idTipologiaEsame;
    }
}
```

and Entity 2

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TipologiaCampione
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tipologia_campione")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TipologiaCampioneRepository")
 */
class TipologiaCampione
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tipologia", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $tipologia;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="matricola", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $matricola;

  /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Esame",mappedBy="campioni")
     */
    private $esami;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set tipologia
     *
     * @param string $tipologia
     *
     * @return TipologiaCampione
     */
    public function setTipologia($tipologia)
    {
        $this->tipologia = $tipologia;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tipologia
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTipologia()
    {
        return $this->tipologia;
    }

    /**
     * Set matricola
     *
     * @param string $matricola
     *
     * @return TipologiaCampione
     */
    public function setMatricola($matricola)
    {
        $this->matricola = $matricola;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get matricola
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMatricola()
    {
        return $this->matricola;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->esami = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add esami
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Esame $esami
     *
     * @return TipologiaCampione
     */
    public function addEsami(\AppBundle\Entity\Esame $esami)
    {
        $this->esami[] = $esami;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove esami
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Esame $esami
     */
    public function removeEsami(\AppBundle\Entity\Esame $esami)
    {
        $this->esami->removeElement($esami);
    }

    /**
     * Get esami
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getEsami()
    {
        return $this->esami;
    }
}
```

now i must save data and in my controller i write this:

```
 for($i=0;$i<$form->get('numero_campioni')->getData();$i++) {
            $campione=new TipologiaCampione();
            $campione->setMatricola($form['matricola_'.$i]->getData());
            $campione->setTipologia($form['tipologia_'.$i]->getData());
         foreach($form['esame_'.$i]->getData() as $value){
                $tipo_esame = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:nome_esame')
            ->find($value->getId());

             $esame=new Esame();
             $esame->setIdAnalisi($analisi);
             $esame->setIdTipologiaEsame($tipo_esame);
             $em->persist($esame);
             $em->flush();

             $campione->addEsami($esame); -> this don't work

         }
         $em->persist($campione);
         $em->flush();
        }
```

I expect that $campione->addEsami($esame); creates a new record in my table esame_tipologia_campione for each $campione but it doesn't work ..

My form Type:

```
<?php



  namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;
    use AppBundle\Entity\anagrafica;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
    use AppBundle\Form\anagraficaType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CurrencyType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
    use AppBundle\Form\EsameType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

    class AnalisiType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $province = array(
            'AG' => 'Agrigento',
            'AL' => 'Alessandria',
            'AN' => 'Ancona',

        );

        $builder->add('ruminanti', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'Tipologia di modulo',
                    'choices' => array('Ruminanti' => 'Ruminanti', 'Suini' => 'Suini'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getTipoModulo() != NULL ? $options['data']->getTipoModulo() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Provincia',
            )))
                ->add('idLaboratorio', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'Laboratorio a cui inviare i dati',
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Laboratorio',
                    'choice_label' => 'nome',
                        // 'data'=>5 
                ))


//                Dati proprietario
                ->add('privato', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'choices' => array('Privato' => 'Privato', 'Azienda' => 'Azienda'),
                    'data' => 'Privato',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                ))
                ->add('Nome_proprietario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getNome() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Nome',
                        'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
            )))
                ->add('Cognome_proprietario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getCognome() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Cognome',
                        'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
            )))
                ->add('Ragione_sociale_proprietario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getRagioneSociale() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Ragione Sociale',
                        'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
            )))
                ->add('Via_proprietario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getvia() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Via'
            )))
                ->add('Comune_proprietario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getComune() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Comune'
            )))
                ->add('Provincia_proprietario', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getProvincia() : ''),
                    'choices' => $province,
                    'placeholder' => 'Provincia'
                ))
                ->add('Telefono_proprietario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->gettel() : NULL),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Telefono'
            )))
                ->add('email_proprietario', EmailType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getemail() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'E-mail'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('Cod_allev_proprietario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdProprietario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getCodiceAllievo() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Codice Allevamento'
            )))

//                Dati Veterinario
                ->add('Nome_veterinario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdVeterinario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getNome() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Nome'
            )))
                ->add('Cognome_veterinario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdVeterinario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdProprietario()->getCognome() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Cognome'
            )))
                ->add('Via_veterinario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdVeterinario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdVeterinario()->getvia() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Via'
            )))
                ->add('Comune_veterinario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdVeterinario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdVeterinario()->getComune() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Comune'
            )))
                ->add('Provincia_veterinario', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdVeterinario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdVeterinario()->getProvincia() : ''),
                    'choices' => $province,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Provincia'
            )))
                ->add('Telefono_veterinario', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdVeterinario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdVeterinario()->getTel() : NULL),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Telefono'
            )))
                ->add('email_veterinario', EmailType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => ($options['data']->getIdVeterinario() != NULL ? $options['data']->getIdVeterinario()->getEmail() : ''),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'E-mail'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('trattamenti', TextareaType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Trattamenti(inserire ANAMNESI; SINTOMATOLOGIA; TRATTAMENTI)'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('vacinazione', TextareaType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Vacinazioni(obbligatorio)'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('numero_campioni', NumberType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Numero Totale di campioni'
                    )
        ));
//->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'));

        $builder->add('idTipologiaEsame', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Nome_esame',
                    'choice_label' => 'nome',
                    'group_by' => 'idCategoriaEsame.tipo',
                ))
                ->add('Aggiungi', ButtonType::class, array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn-primary col-md-2 conferma_esame'),
                ))
                ->add('Rimuovi', ButtonType::class, array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn-primary col-md-2 conferma_esame'),
        ));


//       for($i=0;$i<$options['data']->getNumeroCampioni();$i++){
        for ($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {
            $builder->add('checkbox_' . $i, CheckboxType::class, array(
                        'label' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'attr' => array(
                            'class' => 'check_box_table',
//                   'class'=>'col-md-1 col-xs-3 allineare_sinistra',
                        )
                    ))
                    ->add('matricola_' . $i, TextType::class, array(
                        'label' => false,
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'attr' => array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Matricola (FACOLTATIVA)',
//                        'class'=>'col-md-2 col-xs-9 allineare_sinistra',
                )))
                    ->add('tipologia_' . $i, TextType::class, array(
                        'label' => false,
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'attr' => array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Tipologia (FACOLTATIVA)',
//                        'class'=>'col-md-2 col-md-offset-0  col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3 allineare_sinistra',
                )))
                    ->add('esame_' . $i, EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Nome_esame',
                        'required'=>true,
                        'multiple'=>true,
                    'choice_label' => 'nome',
//                        'disabled' => 'disabled',
                     'attr' => array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Esami',
                            'class' => 'max_width esame_row select_esame',
//                        'class'=>'col-md-12 col-md-offset-0  col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3 ',
                )
                ))

                    ->add('Stampa', ButtonType::class, array(
                        'disabled' => 'disabled',
                        'attr' => array(
                            'class' => 'btn-primary text-center',
                        )
                    ))
                     ->add('saveAndAdd', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save and Add'))
            ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Analisi'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'appbundle_analisi';
    }

}
```

$esame entity and $campione entity are correctly saved.

Can anybody say to me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Did you try the @JoinTable(name="esame_tipologia_campione ") on the inverse side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Join Table](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

After that you need to choose which entity is the owner of the association (just after the manytomany chapter in the doc).
For exampre, if you may want to add "campioni" via the "esami" entity you should code a setter like this:

```
public function addCampioni(\AppBundle\Entity\TipologiaCampione($campioni) {
    $campioni->addEsami($this);
    $this->campioni[] = $campioni;

    return $this;
}
```

Ciao!